# tabs do not wrap container on solution without javascript

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to replace an old tabs setup using **`jquery-ui`**.

I found [this codepen](https://codepen.io/dhs/pen/diasg) that works fine except for an issue with the tabs that do not wrap around the container when there are many of them ( see [this codepen](https://codepen.io/BernardA8/pen/YYrRZr)  ).

It's certainly possible to resolve that with javascript, but I am trying to avoid it for now.

Thanks

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1,
h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.tabs {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 40px auto;
  position: relative;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tabs .tab {
  display: block;
}

.tabs .tab>input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}

.tabs .tab>label {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 80px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #4A83FD;
}

.tabs .content {
  z-index: 0;
  /* or display: none; */
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 27px;
  left: 0;
  background: #303030;
  color: #DFDFDF;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-out;
}

.tabs>.tab>[id^="tab"]:checked+label {
  top: 0;
  background: #303030;
  color: #F5F5F5;
}

.tabs>.tab>[id^="tab"]:checked~[id^="tab-content"] {
  z-index: 1;
  /* or display: block; */
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-out;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="tab">
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" checked="checked" id="tab1" />
    <label for="tab1">One</label>
    <div id="tab-content1" class="content">
      <h1>Tab content 1</h1>
      <hr/>
      <h3>Aliquam tristique orci non facilisis lobortis</h3>
      <br/>
      <img src="https://blog.codepen.io/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Button-Fill-Black-Large.png" width="100" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" />
      <p>Interdum et malesuada </p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="tab">
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2" />
    <label for="tab2">Two</label>
    <div id="tab-content2" class="content">
      <h1>Tab content 2</h1>
      <hr/>
      <h3>Ut bibendum augue vel magna rhoncus</h3>
      <br/>
      <p>Nam cursus, massa ac imperdiet posuer.</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="tab">
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3" />
    <label for="tab3">Three</label>
    <div id="tab-content3" class="content">
      <h1>Tab content 3</h1>
      <hr/>
      <h3>Praesent ac accumsan urna. Mauris lorem purus</h3>
      <br/>
      <p>Suspendisse vulputate nunc ac pretium pulvinar</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="tab">
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab4" />
    <label for="tab4">Four</label>
    <div id="tab-content4" class="content">
      <h1>Tab content 4</h1>
      <hr/>
      <h3>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquen</h3>
      <br/>
      <p>Fusce in malesuada ligula. Donec eleifend dui eu mi condimentum interdum. </p>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: How many tabs do you really want?

Comment: Thanks @BhuwanBhatt. The quantity of tabs is variable. It goes from as little as 2 to as much as 15. So it should be something that adjust automatically.

Comment: You want all the 15 tabs in a single line? Scrollbar option is accepted?

Comment: No, certainly not in a single line. That's exactly the point. The tabs should wrap. If is not clear on my codepen above, take a look at the following page for example. https://www.soeezauto.ma/marques-voiture/BMW

Comment: I added a solution below. Have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, I think you have to change the **`top: 27px`** to **`top: 100%`** in **`.tabs .content`** class.

Fiddle link: https://codepen.io/bhuwanb9/pen/RxLvPP

Check below snippet

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1,
h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.tabs {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 40px auto;
  position: relative;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.tabs .tab {border:1px solid #fff;}

.tabs .tab>input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}

.tabs .tab>label {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #4A83FD;
}

.tabs .content {
  z-index: 0;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #303030;
  color: #DFDFDF;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-out;
}

.tabs>.tab>[id^="tab"]:checked+label {
  top: 0;
  background: #303030;
  color: #F5F5F5;
}

.tabs>.tab>[id^="tab"]:checked~[id^="tab-content"] {
  z-index: 1;
  /* or display: block; */
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-out;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="tab">
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" checked="checked" id="tab1" />
    <label for="tab1">One</label>
    <div id="tab-content1" class="content">
      One
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="tab">
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2" />
    <label for="tab2">Two</label>
    <div id="tab-content2" class="content">
      Two
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="tab">
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3" />
    <label for="tab3">Three</label>
    <div id="tab-content3" class="content">
      Three
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="tab">
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab4" />
    <label for="tab4">Four</label>
    <div id="tab-content4" class="content">
      Four
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="tab">
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab5" />
    <label for="tab5">Five</label>
    <div id="tab-content5" class="content">
      Five
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="tab">
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab6" />
    <label for="tab6">Six</label>
    <div id="tab-content6" class="content">
      Six
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="tab">
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab7" />
    <label for="tab7">Seven</label>
    <div id="tab-content7" class="content">
      Seven
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```